# Apache rewrite / to .html

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make my url's that end in / to change to .html but can't seem to get the correct approach. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far, as well as a working example ? Thanks

Comment: So far I've tried RewriteRule ^/foo(.{0}|/)$  /foo.html [NC,L,R=301] but no luck.

Comment: You might want to escape the "/" in your regex : (.{0}|\/). (It's not a "V" it's "\" before "/" :D

Answer (score 0):

The following will perform the redirect only if the matching directory does not exist.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [NC,R=301,L]
```